# Search expressions parser written in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I am developing an html/javascript app which allows users to search in a local database.
I would like to support very advanced search queries like:
abc | "def ghi" !jkl

I need to parse this kind of complex expressions in order to build the corresponding SQL query.

So, what I am looking for is a flexible parser written in javascript and it should let me define my expression grammar.

Comment: Check out the Sizzle source http://sizzlejs.com/, might find some useful stuff in there.

Comment: Are your users going to be technically savvy enough to understand this syntax? or would you be better off with "regular" keywords or a specialized form/wizard?

Comment: I need to support the sphinx extended syntax since this is what I support on the online version http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#extended-syntax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jison](http://zaach.github.com/jison/) is a JavaScript parser generator, written in JavaScript.

And yes, it is really flexible and lets you define your own grammar.

Answer (score 7):

pegJS : http://pegjs.majda.cz/ should also do the trick.