# Using a Javascript search algorithm on a Django context variable

Tags: javascript, django, fuse.js

What I'm trying to do is offer search functionality on a webpage where all data is displayed when loading the page. The dataset is not very large (think <500 items) so it would be very user-friendly to offer some search functionality that does not require a page refresh (or any requests for that matter). I've looked at some interesting Javascript libraries (summed up in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17536473/1887892)), and especially [Fuse.js](http://kiro.me/projects/fuse.html) and [Lunr.js](http://lunrjs.com) look very suitable for my scenario.

The problem is that I don't know how to apply these libraries -- which seem to search through JSON exclusively -- to the context passed by Django. I have only scratched the surface of the functionality of Django, because I've only started working on it a few days ago, so pardon me if I'm missing something obvious. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to output the JSON in your template. You can either pass it directly from your view via `json.dumps()`, or manually iterate through the data in your template to create the JSON. The first would be preferable.

So, using the Fuse example, your view would do:

```
def my_view(request):
    data = ... get data from wherever ...
    return render(request, 'template.html', {"data": json.dumps(data)})
```

and the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = {{ json_data }}
    var options = ...
    var f = new Fuse(data, options)
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

While Daniel (in the comments) is certainly correct for telling me how to add JSON to the context - I probably should have phrased the question differently. But I digress.

After some more work I am now generating a correct JSON from the object hierarchy. This JSON is passed through the context, and is then used together with [Mustache.js](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/) to generate HTML. I could not figure out a way to pass data as JSON *and* also use Django's templating language to iterate through the JSON. When approaching this from the other direction, I could not figure out a way to convert the regular Django context (e.g. a context with `var.objects.all()`) to JSON on the client-side (because of some silly nonsense with single-quotes..)

Nevertheless generating HTML with Mustache.js was not so bad after all, because this allowed me to easily manipulate the page with the search results generated by the search algorithm (in my case Fuse.js). Hopefully the performance will be al right in production, but it certainly looks very promising!